# Can I manage variables on #Eval inside a repeater?

Tags: c#, .net, eval, repeater

Tried :

```
string immagine = (Eval("Immagine").ToString());
```

inside a C# repeater .ascx, but seems that I can't? *System.InvalidOperationException: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.*

**EDIT**

The only way I found is to write :

```
<%#(Eval("Immagine").ToString() != Eval("Immagine").ToString() ? "" : "")%>
```

Dunno why it doesnt works with an if/else statement...

Comment: What are you trying to do? As the error states, `Eval` is meant to bind data from your datasource to the control.

Comment: I Have to check if value inside Eval("Immagine") is empty or not...

Comment: When I get annoyed with using Eval in a data bound control for whatever reason I just switch to handling `ItemDataBound` in the code behind and doing it there.  It's a bit more verbose, but still less frustrating to me.

Comment: Certainly missed something about what you are trying to achieve, but why don't you use something like <%#((YourNamespace.YourClass)Container.DataItem).Immagine==null?"null":"not null"%> ?